# Stop OpenCV for seventeen seconds? python

Tags: python, opencv, wait, python-2.x

I have a motion detection program in OpenCV, and I want it to play a sound when it detects motion. I use winsound. However, OpenCV still seems to be gathering frames while the sound is playing, so I want to know a way to stop all OpenCV processes for about 17 seconds. I tried time.sleep and running it with the `-u` tag. Neither worked. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by putting what I want to run before resuming processes (playing the sound) in another script, performing `import sound` and breaking out of the loop to stop the program, and I can't figure out how to start it again. For my purposes, I can restart it manually.